# Can I search and extend VS Code settings.json recursively along parents to extend settings?

Tags: architecture, visual-studio-code

```
C:\projects\repo
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───project1
│   │   package-lock.json
│   │   package.json
│   │
│   ├───.vscode
│   │       settings.json
│   │
│   └───src
│           index.js
│
└───project2
    │   package-lock.json
    │   package.json
    │
    ├───.vscode
    │       settings.json
    │
    └───src
            index.js
```

I have a repository which has a folder structure like the diagram above. For several reasons,

1. I want to extend partial settings from repo while having some specific settings for each project.
2. As the repo size grows, opening the whole repo is too heavy for VS Code and too messy. Most of the time I just need to work on a certain project and this is enough.

In the current version of VS Code (v1.43), I don't see any related key to let me override/extend settings.json from parent folders. Anyone know how can I achieve it? Thank you in advance.

Attached 3 samples of settings.json below for your reference.

```
// settings.json of repo, all children projects should extend "source.fixAll.eslint": true
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
}
```

```
// settings.json of project1, extends repo settings with below settings
{
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript"
    ]
}
```

```
// settings.json of project2, extends repo settings with below settings
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "eslint.validate": [
      "typescript"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use Multi Root Workspace. The `.code-workspace` file can contain settings

Comment: @rioV8 I don't know how can multi-root workspace solve my problem. Did you mean that by adding all the projects into workspace as roots then all the projects can extends the code-workspace settings? However, by doing this, we would need to add all projects into workspace beforehand... This breaks my point 2, the workspace will become so messy while the projects grows...

Comment: How far up the directory path should VSC look for `settings.json` files? You then need to add a similar setting to all your project `settings.json` files to mark the `path-up` count. What if you move the project directory you have to change this. You can file a feature request.

Comment: Can you just change the overall user settings.json file to include the settings you want all of the projects to extend? Then, the individual workspace settings could include their own settings

Answer (score 1):

Like you I wanted to share several features between projects, not only the settings but also some tasks and create a default ftp.json

The [VSC Global Config extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.global-config) is my solution (and I think it could be yours).

Here's how it works:

1. Create a folder anywhere on your computer, for instance named *.vscode/global/*
2. Create your default files in this folder, for instance *.vscode/global/settings.json*, 
   *.vscode/global/tasks.json*, *.vscode/global/ftp.json*
3. Install the plugin, enter its settings and locate the folder containing your default config files
4. When you create a project, open the command palette with *ctrl+shift+p* and choose *Copy global config*

It'll copy your default files in your project *.vscode* folder, then you can customize per-project settings